# Parameter passing with bash for clojure

Tags: bash, clojure

I make a clj script for running clojure as follows.

```
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.main $1
```

The problem is that $1 is the name of the script, so I can't pass the argument with this.

The alternatives can be

```
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.main $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
```

hoping that the number of arguments is less than four, which might work, but I guess there should be a better solution to this.

What would be the better way than this?

Comment: take a look at clojure-contrib/launchers/bash/clj-env-dir:
http://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/master/launchers/bash/clj-env-dir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$@` to pass on all CLI arguments received by your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.main $@
```

If you want to omit some initial arguments, you can use e.g. `shift`, which drops the current value of `$1` and shifts the remaining arguments so that `$1` assumes the old value of `$2`, `$2` that of `$3` etc.:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prints out the first CLI argument, then passes the rest on to clojure.main
echo $1
shift
java -cp $CLOJURE_JAR:$CLASSPATH clojure.main $@
```

For related information, see the section entitled `Special Parameters` in `bash`'s manpage.

Comment: `shift` can take an argument, too, if you need to drop more than one at once: `shift 2`, for example.